# Permanent connection in foreground service even in when screen is locked

Tags: android, background-service

So, the goal is to make guaranteed realtime delivered Push Notifications. The problem is that on Android O mqtt connection is just because Mobile Internet connection and Wifi are halted while in sleep mode.

Is there any way to persist connection through sleep mode?

Comment: I think the only way to get guaranteed realtime notifications is to use FCM.

Comment: They are absolutely not guaranteed. That is why We are developing our own solution. Also, FCM push notifications may be delayed (up to 3 weeks?) and we are looking for almost instant delivery

Comment: Firebase is a Google service. I've never had issues with undelivered notifications (except on Chinese software), but if Google can't guarantee notifications on the operating system it made, I'm not sure how far you'll get. Google Services has the advantage of being a privileged system app.

Comment: Does FCM has more frequest Doze and idle network windows?